# AJAX based web application

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

Regardless of what type of web application one could program, implementing AJAX would make the program - albeit arguably - more efficient and "prettier".

I am currently working on an online shop with a complete user interface which includes: order history, wishlist, referral links & more. We've come to the realization that by making many of the user operations executable in AJAX would be much user friendly rather than, for example, refreshing the page every time a user removes a product from the wishlist.

Following that logic would result in a massive amount of files in the, let's say, /ajax directory on the server and absurdly long .js files.

My question is this - is there a certain standard or "trick" when writing a lot of different ajax requests? Or better yet, is there an efficient way to write AJAX requests?

Regards,

Comment: just use one function and reuse whereever you want

Comment: jQuery makes the coding of these kinds of requests pretty small!

Comment: Obviously, what I meant was for all the different requests. Each request does something completely different.

Comment: There are server-side frameworks that automatically generate JavaScript proxies for methods/classes you choose to expose for AJAX consumption. On the Microsoft platform, I believe you can use ASP.NET AJAX to generate proxies for WCF services. See [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515101(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a generic function that makes all data requests

This function could have the arguments

1. Object(key,value) to be sent in the post request
2. function to run when the request is returned

Add a key `&datafunc=somefunctionname` to the request string

On the server side

IF `$_POST` contains the key `datafunc`, run the respective php function which will return the required data

```
$fun=$_POST['datafunc'];
$fun();
```

Comment: For a lack of a better term, it's simply brilliant! I was in fact aiming for a solution similar to this - including all the PHP functions for the AJAX calls in one file.

Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: Glad to help. all the best!

Comment: your example is - simply put - a security nightmare! add at least some kind of validation logic to it, else every time this code is used a kitten dies!

Comment: nietonfir, you're correct IF you embed your code as simple as Shamps posted but this was a mere example of a logic to be put to good use.

Answer (score 4):

Create a JS file and include that file in all pages. In that JS file create a ajax function with 3 parameters.

Parameters Values of ajax function:

1. Page URL want to send request
2. Associative Array of value want to send
3. Element Id want to fill with response from ajax request.

Call this function from any page, so you don't need to create ajax function in each and every page.

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks :) What I actually meant was a way of combining all the functions in one page - e.g. ajax.php - rather than writing separate files all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery.getJSON()` or `jQuery.get()` to do the ajax calls. Well, finally both are translated to `jQuery.ajax()`.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score -2):

The trick is to keep your logic as stupid as possible and have a proper DTO. Now add one of the very powerful Javascript View framework into the mix and your basically done.

Imagine something like the following in the jQuery success callback (without a MVC framework, you populate the elements yourself):

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // data is the DTO as you defined it
    $ele = $(data.target);
    // and now update your target
    $ele.html(data.content);
}
```